# Performance of DELETE with NOT IN (SELECT ...)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, postgresql-performance

I have these two tables and want to delete all authors from ms_author, who are not present in author.

**`author`** (1.6M rows)

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | index |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| id    | text        | NO   | PRI | true  |
| name  | text        | YES  |     |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
```

**`ms_author`** (120M rows)

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | index |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| id    | text        | NO   | PRI |       |
| name  | text        | YES  |     | true  |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
```

This is my query:

```
    DELETE
FROM ms_author AS m
WHERE m.name NOT IN
                   (SELECT a.name
                    FROM author AS a);
```

I tried to estimate the query duration: ~ 130 hours.
Is there a faster way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

`EXPLAIN VERBOSE` output

```
Delete on public.ms_author m  (cost=0.00..2906498718724.75 rows=59946100 width=6)"
  ->  Seq Scan on public.ms_author m  (cost=0.00..2906498718724.75 rows=59946100 width=6)"
        Output: m.ctid"
        Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))"
        SubPlan 1"
          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..44334.43 rows=1660295 width=15)"
                Output: a.name"
                ->  Seq Scan on public.author a  (cost=0.00..27925.95 rows=1660295 width=15)"
                      Output: a.name"
```

Indexing author(`name`):

```
create index author_name on author(name);
```

Indexing ms_author(name):

```
create index ms_author_name on ms_author(name);
```

Comment: I think that using `join` or `exists` will be more performance

Comment: Is text an indexed field?

Comment: I think danihp means, is the author.name column indexed?

Comment: @jarlh: author.name is not indexed, while ms_author is indexed right now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think with "output" you mean the table representation, right? I created it by hand. ;)

Comment: I'd index author.name too.

Comment: what is estimate query duration after index task was finished?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'll index author.name when I get home and check back here with updated results and index statemens.

Comment: enjoy your meal. Was me who asked ;)

Comment: You typically would not have a `text` PK in a table as huge as that. Neither would you have an (undeclared) FK referencing the same. Use `integer` or `bigint` values instead.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: The database was given to me by MS (It's the Microsoft Research Graph) and the ids contain numbers+letters. After the merging procedure I'm trying to do right now there will be bigint ids. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the "anti-join."  This works efficiently for both large and small datasets:

```
delete from ms_author ma
where not exists (
  select null
  from author a
  where ma.name = a.name
)
```

Comment: That's the way to go. `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is a tricky clause. Typically, there are [better alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860).

Comment: Thanks! :) It took about 10 hours. Coming from around 130 hours is a huge improvement! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your delete query using `NOT IN` usually result in a nested loop antijoin which will result in poor performance. You can rewrite your query as follows:

You can write something like this:

```
DELETE FROM ms_author AS m
WHERE m.id IN
               (SELECT m.id FROM ms_author AS m
                LEFT JOIN author AS a ON m.name = a.name
                WHERE a.name IS NULL);
```

This approach has as additional advantage that you are using the primary key 'id'  to delete rows and this should be much faster.